# Making parallax background images work with bxslider / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, bxslider

I am trying to have 3 parallax background images on a page which seem to work ok, but I also need to have them have a carousel effect so I'm using bxslider with the parallax code.

The first slide shows up (although it isn't showing up at 100% width), but the other two images in the slider don't.

This is the style I'm using:

```
.parallax {
background-size:cover;
min-height:1224px;
overflow:auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="carousel">
<ul class="bxslider">                 
    <li class="parallax" style="background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">

        <div class="parallax" style="border: 1px solid red; background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">...</div>

    </li>
    <li class="parallax" style="background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">

        <div class="parallax" style="border: 1px solid red; background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">...</div>

    </li>      
    <li class="parallax" style="background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">

        <div class="parallax" style="border: 1px solid red; background-image:url(images/test2.jpg);">...</div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure if links are allowed, but the page I'm working on can be seen here: http://ldswebsites.co.uk/intone/test.html

It seems that it's the background-attachment: fixed is what is causing the issue as when I take that out the images on the carousel show up, but it loses the parallax effect on the rest of the images. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, I managed to fix the issue I was having. Don't know if this question can be deleted or not :)

Comment: Don't delete your question, post an answer explaining your solution, I for one would like to know how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

The author didn't post his answer
So to fix this issue, I **removed background-attachment:fixed**, because it was cousing problems
and I **added a function** to simulate parallax image.

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('myBxSlider li').css('background-position',"0 "+  (scrolled * 1) + 'px');
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    parallax();
});
```

I copied this code from this link:https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/translate-3d-fixed-background-on-slick-slide/244637/7 
Answer posted by **RyanReese**